# Unable to download apps from Market, after factory reset

Tags: google-play-store, downloading

***Problem description***

I did factory reset of my phone, (Droid X), and I changed primary email, and I am not able to download any application from market. I get a message like application will be downloaded, but its never download app .

And I am using this same email id, as test account in developer account.

How can I download application from market? I am using wifi network.

Comment: are you downloading from the website or from the phone app? have you tried both?

Comment: Yes I tried both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try clearing the data for the Market app:

1. Go to `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> All` and find the Market app
2. If it's running, kill it with the button there
3. Clear the data (this will clear the cache as well, no need to do both manually)
4. Restart your phone

Then try the Market again.

**Edit:** Since that didn't work, I would try [wiping the data partition](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Motorola_Droid_X%3a_Full_Update_Guide#Second_Method_.28via_Recovery.29) (similar to a factory reset):

1. Power off your phone
2. Boot into bootloader mode by holding down Volume Down, Power, and the Camera button.
3. Pull the battery and power back on while holding the Home button. Once you see an Android with the triangle & exclamation point, press the Search button.
4. Using the side volume buttons to move around and the Power button to select, select the "Wipe Data" option.
5. Once the wipe is finished, select "Reboot system now".

Comment: I did it, but problem is same.

Comment: @pankaj Hmm. I would try wiping the data partition at this point, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Now I am unable to start my phone. When I pulled the battery, phone went to off and till then I am not able start my phone. Please help me.

Comment: @pankaj That's very strange, pulling the battery while it's sitting at the bootloader shouldn't have hurt anything. Try a few more battery pulls and holding various keys while you power on, and try with and without USB plugged in (make sure the phone is charged as well).  If that doesn't work, from what I understand you need to use RSDlite to re-flash your ROM. Instructions are [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0jrXqqiepI), though I haven't tested them myself ... use your judgement.  Good luck!